# php pdo mysql fetch returns a general error?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

When trying to do this:

```
        // make unread notifications
        $db->sqlquery("SELECT `participant_id` FROM `user_conversations_participants` WHERE `conversation_id` = ? AND `participant_id` != ?", array($_POST['conversation_id'], $_SESSION['user_id']));
        while ($participants = $db->fetch())
        {
            $db->sqlquery("UPDATE `user_conversations_participants` SET `unread` = 1 WHERE `participant_id` = ?", array($participants['participant_id']));
        }
```

I seem to get this error:

> Warning: PDOStatement::fetch() [pdostatement.fetch]: SQLSTATE[HY000]:
>   General error in
>   /home/gamingon/public_html/prxa.info/includes/class_mysql.php on line
>   68

Here is my query and fetch functions:

```
// the main sql query function
public function sqlquery($sql, $objects = array())
{
    global $core;

    try
    {
        $this->STH = $this->database->prepare($sql);

        foreach($objects as $k=>$p)
        {
            // +1 is needed as arrays start at 0 where as ? placeholders start at 1 in PDO
            if(is_numeric($p))
            {
                $this->STH->bindValue($k+1, (int)$p, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            }
            else
            {
                $this->STH->bindValue($k+1, $p, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            }
        }

        $this->counter++;

        return $this->STH->execute();
    }

    catch (Exception $e)
    {
        $core->message($e->getMessage());
    }
}

public function fetch()
{
    $this->STH->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
    **return $this->STH->fetch();**
}
```

Comment: can you highlight the line 68?

Comment: Why not use an `UPDATE ... SELECT`?

Comment: I have highlighted like 68 with stars each side.

Comment: For googlers; if your query needs MySQL variables, you need to execute their initialization (`SET ...`) in their own query.

Answer (score 4):

During the first iteration of the loop, you overwrite the `STH` property of the `$db` instance. In other words:

1. You do a SELECT query, `$db->STH` is a SELECT prepared statement.
2. You do a `fetch()` call on the SELECT statement, which works.
3. First loop iteration: You overwrite `$db->STH` with an UPDATE prepared statement.
4. Just before the second loop iteration: You can't do a `fetch()` call anymore, because the SELECT statement is gone, an INSERT statement is in its place.

Refactor your database class or make a new instance of `$db`'s class (with a different variable name!) for use in the loop.

Comment: That was it exactly so i changed it to fetch all, then foreach loop it :), thank you!

Comment: I wish I could upvote this answer 10 times! I was doing something exactly as stupid inside loops. :D